# any precautions required when opening local file?

Tags: linux, bash

I found the following within one of our scripts:

```
SCRIPT_LOCATION=$(pwd)
SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$(dirname ${SCRIPT_LOCATION})"
CONFIG_FILE="${SCRIPT_DIRECTORY}/.saved-settings"
```

The idea is basically: the script then checks if that file exists; and the saved settings are loaded.

It seems that running pwd and dirname ... doesn't add any value. Is the above *better* than a simple

```
CONFIG_FILE="./.saved-settings"
```

If so - in which ways?

Comment: `SCRIPT_LOCATION=pwd` doesn't even make sense, maybe `SCRIPT_LOCATION=$(pwd)`?

Comment: Or you could do  `SCRIPT_LOCATION="$PWD"`

Comment: Wow. So much about the quality of that script. But just for the record - with that change in place ... what about my question then?

Comment: @GhostCat Use fully qualified paths unless you can guarantee that the user will always be in the correct directory before sourcing/running the script. you could also `cd` at the start but full paths are better.

Comment: @anubhava dir lists the directory...

Comment: @123 I dont get your comment. How do I get to full paths here?

Comment: @GhostCat Type them manually.

Comment: @ghostcat: What 123 is saying is: you don't always have to do `cd /path/to/script; ./myscript.sh` User could have done `cd /path/to; ./script/myscript.sh`. In that case, `$(pwd)` will be `/path/to` and your config file is in `/path/to/script`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One semantical difference between

```
SCRIPT_LOCATION="$(pwd)"
SCRIPT_DIRECTORY="$(dirname ${SCRIPT_LOCATION})"
CONFIG_FILE="${SCRIPT_DIRECTORY}/.saved-settings"
```

and

```
CONFIG_FILE="../.saved-settings"
```

(notice the two dots) is in the case when the current directory is a symlink. In that case, `dirname` will treat the path as a string and will remove the last component of it (e.g. `/foo/bar/baz` will become `/foo/bar`), but the `..` operator will take you to the parent directory of the symlink target. So if the current directory is `/foo/bar/baz` which is a symlink to `/aaa/bbb/ccc` then the first snippet will return `/foo/bar` whereas the second one will return `/aaa/bbb`.

Comment: So, you are the **newbie** who makes 3K reputation in a few weeks. Nice to meet you!

Comment: @GhostCat 4k by end of the week I suppose :) :)

Comment: Probably a new bot by Jon Skeet that he wrote because he is bored. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts ... the answer by Don Dryer.